# How to check for an empty document?

Tags: office-js

I have a requirement to detect if document is empty and if yes display a prompt to the user using Word Add-in.

Is there a way to detect an empty document from within OfficeJS Word Add-in or through API?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to get the document's ParagraphCollection and perform your check using that, something like this:

```
Word.run(function (context) {
    var paragraphs = context.document.body.paragraphs;
    context.load(paragraphs, 'text');

    return context.sync().then(function () {
        if (paragraphs.items.length === 0) {
            // Empty document!
        }
    });
});
```

This will work for a completely blank document. You will need to add additional checks against each `paragraphs.items[]` object's `text` property if you wish to be more rigorous.

[Source](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/word/paragraphcollection)

Comment: This doesn't take header and footer text into consideration which is why I posted this question looking for a leaner solution.

Comment: You can use context.document.sections to access headers/footers, which are Body objects (and have their own ParagraphsCollections). [Source](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/word/sectioncollection)

Comment: Alternatively, you could load context.document.body, call body.getOoxml(), and use regular expressions to find any existing paragraph (`<w:p>`), run (`<w:r>`), and text (`<w:t>`) tags. I believe this would account for headers and footers as well. [getOoxml ref](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/word/body#getooxml), [OOXML ref](http://officeopenxml.com/WPparagraph.php)

Comment: I'm not sure if headers/footers are the only missing things in your original proposed solution. How can I truly make sure that the document is indeed empty?

Comment: The ooxml for a new blank document has exactly one `<w:p>` tag, which contains no child elements other than property tags. So a truly blank document would also have only one `<w:p>` tag with only properties children and the same for its header and footer. It is possible to check this with regular expressions, but I am not aware of any similar functionality within the scope of the office.js API.

Comment: In a truly empty document, I get following ooxml inside `<w:body>` tag:
`<w:p w:rsidR="00D07999" w:rsidRDefault="00D07999" w:rsidP="00D07999"/>
        <w:p w:rsidR="00000000" w:rsidRDefault="00D07999"/>
        <w:sectPr w:rsidR="00000000">
            <w:pgSz w:w="12240" w:h="15840"/>
            <w:pgMar w:top="1440" w:right="1440" w:bottom="1440" w:left="1440" w:header="720" w:footer="720" w:gutter="0"/>
            <w:cols w:space="720"/>
            <w:docGrid w:linePitch="360"/>
        </w:sectPr>`
If you see there are couple of `<w:p>` tags

Comment: Are you sure that the document does not have two paragraphs? When I open a new Word document, save it, and examine document.xml I find only one `<w:p>` tag, but if I first hit Enter and create a second paragraph, then my document.xml resembles the ooxml you provided. Nevertheless, you'll notice there are no `<w:t>` tags (much less any `<w:r>` tags) which must enclose any text. You must decide whether to consider a document containing some blank paragraphs to be empty or not.

Comment: First of all, thanks for your quick responses. Sorry, I missed out thanking you earlier. I created a fresh Word Add-in project in VS; set Add-in project properties > Start Document > [New Word Document] and added a button on page which upon clicking gets the above ooxml using body.getOoxml() method.

Comment: Got a near perfect solution using `document.getFileAsync(Office.FileType.Text,..)` method which returns all the text from the document. For an empty document, the method returns `\r\n` which can be replaced with empty string so essentially an empty document represents empty text which will be matched against final document text (after replacing `\r\n`). I said near perfect as this doesn't consider empty tables, images or objects inserted into document. However, it works fine for content controls due to watermark/placeholder text inside them.

Answer (score 0):

```
Word.run(function(context) {
                    var body = context.document.body;
                    body.load();
                    return context.sync().then(function() {
                        if(body.text.trim().length) {
                           //Document is not Empty. Add your code here you want to run in this case.
                        }
                        else
                            //Empty Document
                    });
                });
```

**body.text.trim().length** returns the number of characters in the document. In case of empty doc length will be **0** and condition will evaluate to false and else part is executed.